# Is there a way to pull first column value in VBA inside e-mail body?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm struggling to find a way to pull the first column value matching with the same row from the `cell.value` found and insert it on the email body.
In others words: Where there is the word "Send" on my worksheet it should grab the matching name from the same row in the first column ("A") and put it on my text body.
Is this possible?

My code below

```vb
Sub email()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range 
    
    Set r = Range("F2:F100")
    
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "Send" Then
            Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
            Email_Cc, Email_Body As String
    
            Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
            Dim Machine_Code As Long
            Dim Machine_Type As Long
    
            Email_Subject = "Reminder to perform activity"
            Email_Send_From = "George@JKhoney.com"
            Email_Send_To = "xsoxperience@JKhoney.com"
            Email_Cc = ""
            Email_Body = "Dear, This is a friendly reminder. There are pending actions regarding your activities please take actions accordingly" & ". Due date on " & cell.Value & "               This is an automatic e-mail with no response needed"
    
            On Error GoTo debugs
    
            Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    
            With Mail_Single
                .Subject = Email_Subject
                .To = Email_Send_To
                .CC = Email_Cc
                .Body = Email_Body
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next

debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Call email_2
End Sub
```

Comment: `cell.entirerow.cells(1).value`? `cell.offset(0, -5).value`? `cell.entirerow.columns("A").value`? `application.intersect(cell.entirerow, cell.worksheet.columns("A")).value`?

Comment: Thank you so much, all of the solutions worked just fine! You're the best.